# Angular - object Object, typescript

Tags: angular, http, object, dictionary

Angular return object, something like this -> [image]
I can't get data to view. Trying {{exchanges | json}} but it showed nothing in the view.

In component code

```
  exchanges: Exchange[] = [];

  constructor(private exchangeService: ExchangeService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.exchangeService.getExchange2()
      .subscribe(
        exchanges => this.exchanges = exchanges
      );
  }
```

In service code

```
  private apiUrl = 'HERE URL TO API';
  exchanges: Exchange[];
  exchange: Exchange;

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getExchange2(): Observable<Exchange[]> {
    let headers = new Headers({'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    return this.http
      .post(this.apiUrl, null, options)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    console.log(body);
    return body || { };
  }
```

exchange.ts

```
export class Exchange {
  constructor(
    public ask: string,
    public exchangeRate: string,
    public bid: string,
    public change: string
  ) {}
}
```

I don't know how to display the content. I looked at google but resolve that I found doesn't work.

Comment: If `console.log(body);` is printing that to the console, why are you returning `body.data` ?

Comment: Oh sorry. That was test. In my code I have only body tag.